# How can I map an array of strings to a linear interpolation between two colors in d3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, d3.js, scale

If you have an array of strings and you want to generate a scale that maps from the strings to a linear interpolation between two color values, what would be the simplest way to do that with d3? Below is my attempt which seems not to have worked the way I wanted it to:

```
var data = [
    {
        category: 'String 1'
    },
    {
        category: 'String 2'
    },
    {
        category: 'String 3'
    }
]; // this could be any length, and also expecting repeat categories

var categories = d3.set(
        data.map(function (datum) {
            return datum.category;
        })
    ).values();

var index = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(categories)
    .range(
        categories.map(function (category, index) {
            return index;
        })
    );

var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(index.range())
    .range(['#00D6F7', '#165966']);

color(index('String 3')); // #2C0000 instead of #165966 like I wanted
color(index('String 2')); // #165966 instead of halfway between the two colors
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a [custom interpolator](https://github.com/NickQiZhu/d3-cookbook/blob/master/src/chapter4/custom-interpolator.html).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Actually I found the issue, it's that `domain` should be `.domain([0, categories.length - 1])` but I was wondering if someone could provide a complete example of a simpler way. Thanks for the link though.